Why is my colour not the same, despite having followed a tutorial
I'm relatively new to Blender VFX, and I've been following a tutorial. When he uses base colour and emission colour, I do the same, but my colour is not the same.


I've looked for other posts about this but can't find anything.
I know it's not really a big deal, but I do want to know why this is.
Any help would be much appreciated :)

I guess they have different Color Management settings in the tutorial.

Ah ok thanks :)

It worked! Thank you so much! :D @gordon-brinkmann

Please post the answer to the question as an answer, so it won't show up as unanswered anymore. :-)
